# any libraries for client broker server system in c++

Tags: c++, header, client-server, broker

I have been working on this thing for client broker server system but i am not getting like what i can do with it as i have previously made my client server without broker using winsock.
I have an idea also about message queues from here :-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707133(v=vs.85).aspx 
like :-

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "mq.h"
#include "tchar.h"
HRESULT CreateMSMQQueue(
                        LPWSTR wszPathName, 
                        PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor,
                        LPWSTR wszOutFormatName,
                        DWORD *pdwOutFormatNameLength
                        )
{

  // Define the maximum number of queue properties.
  const int NUMBEROFPROPERTIES = 2;
```

But any header files or references for client broker server sysytems and mom middleware. Any header file will do in windows c++.

Comment: I am confused now.  What exactly is your question?  That code fragment is related to MSMQ, but you also mention ZeroMQ (which is an entirely different product and even concept).

Comment: my question is header files or any online references for implementation of mom middleware like there is one for msmq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every MOM that has C or C++ bindings (and most do) provides these headers, for the open source ones just download them from their respective sites.

Here are a few more open source ones to get started: [www.rabbitmq.com](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) [activemq.apache.org](http://activemq.apache.org/) [mq.java.net](http://mq.java.net/).  You'll notice that these are all at the base JMS products but they all have multiple language bindings, including C/C++

However, compared to Java where the API is a standard ( [JMS 1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) ) that is not the case for C++ API's as far as I know.  This means that headers will only have significance in the context of an application that's based on the corresponding product, and as such their educational value will be rather limited.

If you want more information have a look at the documentation collections that accompany these products.  Professionally I use OpenMQ a lot, and in my opinion its commercial background really shows in the [documentation collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/)